# in_array returns true if needle is 0

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I have an issue with `in_array` function. Test below returns `true`:

```
in_array(0, array('card', 'cash'))
```

How is it impossible, how can I prevent it ?

However

```
in_array(null, array('card', 'cash'))
```

returns `false`.

Comment: (int) 0 in (int)'card'?

Comment: LOOSE TYPING... you're comparing number with string, so the string is converted to a number, giving 0 in this case, and 0 == 0. Use the optional STRICT argument

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Casting any string that doesn't start with a digit to a number results in `0` in PHP. And this is exactly what happens when comparing `0` with some string. See the [PHP docs](http://de.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for details about how comparisons between various types are done.

Use the third argument (set it to `true`) of [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) to avoid loose type comparison.

```
in_array(0, array('card', 'cash'), true) === false
```

Comment: All right, that's the answer that I need. Thank you !

Answer (score 7):

when you compare in `in_array`
string is converted to int while comparing incompatible data types
it means `cash`or `card` is converted to `0`

This is all because of type casting

You have 2 options

1 . Type casting

```
in_array(string(0), array('card', 'cash'))) === false;
```

2 .Use `third parameter` on in_array to `true` which will match the datatypes

```
in_array(0, array('card', 'cash'), true) === false;
```

see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: OOPS !! bit late to answer that ..

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent it by using the 'strict' parameter:

```
var_export(in_array(0, array('card', 'cash'), true));

var_export(in_array(null, array('card', 'cash'), true));
```

returns false in both cases.

From [the docs to in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array()
function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack.
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer can be casting `0` to string, so:

```
in_array((string) 0, array('card', 'cash'))
```

Keep in mind that `0` can be some variable, so casting can be helpful.